# How to integrate timereport after checkin in TFS?

Tags: tfs, checkin

We would like to integrate an extra popup/prompt when a user checks in something and associating it with a work item. The prompt should ask the user how much time he spent and how much time is left on the work item. This will work as timesheet material for the timereport and invoice. Has anybody any experience to share in this matter? Is this a Check-in policy? A web service trigger? Is it possible?

Comment: May there is sense to think about time tracking tool like TX Chrono (http://www.teamexpand.com/product/tx-chrono). It provides you with simple web-based user interface, reporting functionality and bidirectional sync with TFS

Answer (score 0):

A custom check-in policy is your best bet.  Certainly possible to do that way.

The downside is that it won't catch people just updating a work item without checking things in.

Comment: Thanks, I found a project on CodePlex that used check-in policy as you suggested, it was not very updated and I had problems getting it to run on TFS 2010 but it is a good start. The project can be found here: http://timethattask.codeplex.com/


Thank you Martin, if anyone else has more input on this it would be very helpful!